# HTML encoding at Jboss / Apache level for handling XSS cross site scripting

Tags: javascript, apache, jboss, xss

Our website was recently attacked with XSS cross site scripting - type 1, I went through a couple of websites and they have advised us to do HTML encoding / escaping the escapes / and scanning the URL's (using a filter).

We have fixed the URL cross site scripting by scanning the URL using a filter and we clear the URL before proceeding to the controller (Servlet).

As for information, we have tried something called "Mod_j security" provided by apache, 
but my concern is

how can I endcode the HTML output ?? and is there any configuration setting in JBOSS or Apache to do a HTML encoding before display ??

Please advice me on this as it is critical and needs to be addressed at the earliest.

Comment: This should be done by the application framework  you are using. The webserver only sees the full blob of HTML sent back and cannot know which parts should be html-encoded and which shouldn't.

Comment: We are using the spring framework, and struts tiles definition as view .. so I am not sure where I need to do the encoding !!

Answer (score 1):

XSS defense requires contet awareness during output. See the OWASP XSS prevention cheat sheet. You have to do it within your application. Doing it in a filter or apache would be nice, bur it's just not possible. A ThiefMaster mentioned above it sees just the full output. It's almost impossible to find the attack at this point because there is such a vast amount of possible attacks.